# Having x,y coordinates from 0-9 on a 2d dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code for a board game, however I'm unable to add my x,y coordinates 0-9. Can anyone help?

```
String[][] board = new String [10][10];
for (String[] board1 : board) {
    for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) {
        board1[c] = ".";
    }
}

for (String[] board1 : board) {
    for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) {
        System.out.print(board1[c] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Hey Sarah, we would need to see your (relevant) code in order to help. Also, a somewhat more specific question would help.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hiya Domdom,   this is my code for the board, however i need the 0-9 appear on the x,y angle which im struggling on.                                                                                      String[][] board = new String [10][10];
        for (String[] board1 : board) {
            for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) {
                board1[c] = ".";
            }
        }

               for (String[] board1 : board) {
            for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) {
                System.out.print(board1[c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[][] board = new String [9][9]; 
    for (String[] board1 : board) 
    { 
        for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) 
        { 
            board1[c] = "."; 
        } 
    }

    System.out.print("0");
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    System.out.println();
    int i = 1;
    for (String[] board1 : board) 
    {
        System.out.print((i++) + " ");
        for (int c = 0; c <board.length; c++) 
        { 
            System.out.print(board1[c] + " "); 
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Just play with the code a little and you can get it. Practice making small changes and running the code, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, you should try to ask a very specific question and show the code that you have attempted in your question. See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This is your present code, from what I understand:

```
String[][] board = new String[10][10];
for(String[] board1 : board){
    for(int c=0; c<board.length; c++){
        System.out.println(board1[c] + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

This is what you want to be outputted:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 - - - - - - - - -
2 - - - - - - - - -
3 - - - - - - - - -
4 - - - - - - - - -
5 - - - - - - - - -
6 - - - - - - - - - 
7 - - - - - - - - -
8 - - - - - - - - -
9 - - - - - - - - -
```

**This is how your question should have been asked.**

For the answer, you have to think of the program as having two steps. The first step is setting the values of the array, and the second step is printing it out.

For the first step, just use a loop nested in another loop:

```
    for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<board[0].length; j++){
            if(i==0){ //if the cell is in the first row, set it to the column number
                board[i][j] = Integer.toString(j);
            } else if(j==0){ //if the cell is in the first column, set it to the row number
                board[i][j] = Integer.toString(i);
            } else{
                board[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
    }
```

Now that the values are set, you have to print them. Think of it as printing each row, one at a time. Within each row, you print the column values one at a time.

```
    for(int row=0; row<board.length; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<board[0].length; column++){
            System.out.print(board[row][column] + " "); //after each value, add a space
        }
        System.out.println(); //at the end of each row, go to the next line
    }
```

Note that this code adds an extra space at the end of each line.